# Right limit superior and inferior of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

My text defines left limit inferior and superior as follows:

If $ f$ is bounded on $ [a,x_0)$: 
 Let $ S_f(x; x_0) = \sup\limits_{x \leq t < x_0} f(t) $,   $I_f(x; x_0) = \inf\limits_{x \leq t < x_0} f(t) $.

Then the left limit superior = $ \lim\limits_{x \to x_0^-} S_f(x; x_0) $,  left limit inferior = $ \lim\limits_{x \to x_0^- } I_f(x; x_0) $.

However there is no mention of a right limit superior or right limit inferior, and I was wondering how one could define them in a similar manner.

Comment: $f$ bounded on $(x_0,a].$ Change $x\leqslant t<x_0$ to $x_0<t\leqslant x$, and $x\to x_0^-$ to $x\to x_0^+$.